# Initial Velocity Vector and Parametrics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, parametric

I have a project where we have to throw an object and find the velocity of it. I have found the parametric equations of the path of the object to be: 
$$x(t) = 0.627273t + (-0.211364)$$
$$y(t) = -0.658275t^2 + 1.96578t + 0.014545$$

Here is the graph:
[image]

Now, we are supposed to find the vector components and then calculate the initial velocity vector, without using physics formulas. How would I approach doing this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Calculus?

Comment: @TomHimler not sure, just Pre-Calc stuff I guess.

Comment: @JenkinsMa Are you aware about simple derivatives?

Comment: This isn't a full answer because I'm skirting around Calculus ideas, but if you find the average rate of change for two points very close to your initial value of t, then you can approximate the velocity vector around there, since velocity is the rate of change of position with respect to time.

Comment: Is there a possibility to do it with trig instead?

Comment: I do no think so.

Comment: @JenkinsMa Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that the velocity vector is given by

$$v(t)=(\dot x(t),\dot y(t))$$

with

- $\dot x(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}\approx \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$
- $\dot y(t)=\frac{dy}{dt}\approx \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}$